# What is this name of the video effect?

Tags: effects, special-effects

I got this from les mesirables (2012) movie. in this scene, guy singing, but camera blur all his around, focusing only on him. [image]

so What is this name of the video effect?

Answer (score 3):

Shallow [depth of field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_focus) or focus.

Comment: Note that things are out of focus because they are farther from the camera. That means that if something is just as close as the actor is, it will be IN FOCUS. When you shoot a shot with a shallow depth of field, you will get a better effect if the background is far from the camera and the subject (the guy singing) is close to the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Mulvya is right - it's shallow depth of field, achieved by having a lens with a wide open [aperture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture), corresponding to a low [F stop number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-number).